# Closure variable undefined: How to access outer variables in JS?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, wrapper

I have an event listener that responds with a callback.
This callback is a wrapper around the actual callback.
I have defined a variable in the outermost function, `blockNumber`, and want to access it (read/write) from the innermost function.

The code is as follows.

```
startWeb3 = async () => { 
  await initWeb3();

  var blockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
  console.log(blockNumber) //=> "184"

  window.KYCinstance.events.ReportedFraudA({ fromBlock:0 }, 
  (error, event) => {
    console.log(blockNumber); //=> "184"
    listenCallback(error, event, "fromFraudEvents");
  });

listenCallback = async (error, event, type) => {
  if (error) { console.log(error); }
  else {
    console.log(blockNumber); //=> "ERROR"
  }
}
```

The result is an error message, and of course if I do `this.blockNumber` it is an undefined variable.

`startWeb3` is the outtermost function,
it has an event listener that calls `listenCallback`,
it is inside this callback where I am trying to reach back out the outermost scope.

Comment: Can you please be more clear as to which function here is your `innermost` and which one is the `outermost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MDN definition

> A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment
>   within which that function was declared.

So going by the above definition, `listenCallback` doesn't have a declared in its lexical scope when it is declared itself. `listenWrapperFrom` or `listenCallback` will receive variables from its closure where they are declared and not where they are referenced.

In order to solve this, you could define blockNumber in the lexical scope of `listenCallbackFrom` and `listenCallback` method

```
var blockNumber;

listenToEvent = async () => { 

  blockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();

  KYCinstance.events.ReportedFraudA({ fromBlock:0 }, listenWrapperFrom); 

};

function listenWrapperFrom(error, event) {
  listenCallback(error, event, "fromFraudEvents");
}

async function listenCallback (error, event, type) {
  if (error) { console.log(error); }
  else {
    console.log(blockNumber);
    let value = await someFunction();
  }
}
```